# Are the unreviewed changes counts increasing on SO?

Tags: discussion, suggested-edits, review

Several times today, I've seen over 30 questions needing reviewing; it was reading 40 when I decided to ask this question.

- Is the number of unreviewed changes increasing?

Has it reached a point where you need to be a registered user with some (not necessarily high) reputation to make such suggested changes?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To prevent queue overload there is already in place a cap on the queue size (although, I'm not sure what this is) and the restriction that anonymous users cannot touch brand new posts (source: [FAQ](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/76251/how-do-suggested-edits-work)).

Remember that 2K users can edit without suggesting, and until recently this was the *only* way for users to edit. As such, all the suggested edits are a *bonus* to us, from those without the direct privilege to edit wanting to help, and these are mostly valuable. We don't want to discourage too many of these, otherwise what's the point in having the suggested edits mechanism?

Statistics on the rep ranges of users making these suggested edits would be most useful; to determine if a rep requirement would be effective or not, and how many edits it will deflect.

I'm personally of the opinion that the current setup is sufficient, although I realise that the SO experiences a much higher volume of these things (well everything) than other sites on the network.

However, in case a change *is* deemed necessary, can I offer an alternative solution: lower the rep boundary for people gain access to the `/review` tool that lets them access the suggested edit queue, increasing the number of approvers instead of decreasing the number of editors.